# what is the difference between, the following two while loops logics.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, logic, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to implement the following code.
I tried 2 approaches (2 while loops) here. which are identical, at least to me. but one of the solution i.e approach 2 converging towards a solution.
while approach 1 is not.
can you help me figure out whats the difference between the two approaches.
Note : I used loopIndex just to keep track in which loop the execution is. 
I am trying to terminate the loop if taking too long.
thanks.

```
# this program tries to guess the target string
# using genetic algorithm.

import random
genList = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"
target = "Hello"

# generates a random string under provided length
def generateGuess(_length):
    gene = []
    for i in range(_length) :
        gene.append(random.choice(genList))
    return "".join(gene)

# gets the total no of letters matched from string provided, to target string
def getFitness(gene):
    return sum(1 for geneVar, targetVar in zip(gene, target) if geneVar == targetVar)

# changes 1 letter of the string provided, at a random position.
def mutate (gene):
    newGene, alternate = random.sample(genList, 2)
    gene = list(gene)
    index = random.randint(0, len(gene) - 1)
    gene[index] = alternate if gene[index] == newGene else newGene
    return "".join(gene)

# to display the string provided with its fitness calculated.
def display(gene):
    print("Gene : {0}, Fitness : {1}".format(gene, getFitness(gene)))


# Approach 1 -------------------------------------
child = generateGuess(len(target))
bestFitness = 0
loopIndex = 0

while True :  
    loopIndex = loopIndex + 1
    child = mutate(child)
    if loopIndex > 16800 :
        break
    childFitness = getFitness(child)
    display(child)
    print(loopIndex)
    if childFitness > bestFitness :
        bestFitness = childFitness
    if childFitness >= len(target):
        break

# Approach 2 -------------------------------------
bestParent = generateGuess(len(target))
bestFitness = getFitness(bestParent)
display(bestParent)
loopIndex = 0 

while True:
    loopIndex = loopIndex + 1
    child = mutate(bestParent)
    childFitness = getFitness(child)
    display(child)
    print(loopIndex)
    if bestFitness > childFitness:
        continue
    if childFitness >= len(bestParent):
        break
    bestFitness = childFitness
    bestParent = child
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is the following:

- In the first approach, you **always** replace the current gene even if its fitness is worse (you always set `child=mutate(child)`).
- In the second approach, you keep mutating the **same base gene** over and over (without replacing it) until you improve the fitness and **only then** you replace it with the improved gene just obtained (you only set `bestParent=child` when fitness has improved).

Hope this helps.

Comment: makes sense. Thank you very much.